# How to use the polkadot/dev project template

Tags: polkadot-js, javascript

I'm trying to convert my project over to a structure similar to the `@polkadotjs` repositories, but I'm finding the dev template provided a bit difficult to parse. Specifically:

1. How do I use this repository as a base for my monorepo? Do I fork the repo and work off of it or is there a cli setup?
2. How do I use the dev template package in the repo to create a new app/package in `packages`?  - the `package.json` is hard to parse. I would like to be able to build, test, lint my app/package without worrying too much about config. But I can't find any scripts that do that, only a list of bins, which is quite different from the `@polkadotjs/apps` repo.

Note: I am aiming for a similar setup as the `@polkadotjs` monorepos with one for packages (including typegen) and another for apps. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [polkadot-js dev](https://github.com/polkadot-js/dev) repo is not a template project for helping with using the `@polkadot/*` libs, rather it is a set of templates, configs and scripts that helps all the polkadot-js repos to be consistent in terms of structure and coding.

What this means internally to the polkadot-js org -

- There is a single shared [config](https://github.com/polkadot-js/dev/tree/master/packages/dev/config) for everything - this means that each other repo (be it api, extension, apps, common, phishing, ...) just re-uses the config, be it for [Babel](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/blob/45525b4288922bea8f5df5929061d4b749a25d25/babel.config.cjs#L4), [eslint](https://github.com/polkadot-js/common/blob/81f8f16b983c339b7ce2569e59dabb36a8ff5af0/.eslintrc.js#L4), [Typescript](https://github.com/polkadot-js/tools/blob/ea0d90a08771b3187555081c0371228b120d9d8a/tsconfig.base.json#L2), etc.
- There are a set of [scripts](https://github.com/polkadot-js/dev/tree/master/packages/dev/scripts) that perform build steps - this means that each polkadot-js repo just calls into `@polkadot/dev` for [build](https://github.com/polkadot-js/phishing/blob/67ecbeef18332d4a0f7c37097707416457622440/package.json#L18), [linting](https://github.com/polkadot-js/phishing/blob/67ecbeef18332d4a0f7c37097707416457622440/package.json#L24), [publishing](https://github.com/polkadot-js/phishing/blob/67ecbeef18332d4a0f7c37097707416457622440/package.json#L20), etc.
- There are a set of shared [dev dependencies](https://github.com/polkadot-js/dev/blob/08dffcc3808232fa8b508e49482d41f58fc3f9bd/packages/dev/package.json#L41) for all repos - this means that instead of managing versions for all of the above all-over, it is handled in a specific location and updates can be done seamlessly (obviously code-specific deps go into their normal places inside the repos)
- Internally to this repo the [src/](https://github.com/polkadot-js/dev/tree/master/packages/dev/src) is never used anywhere - it is there to test the scripts/configs as changes are made. So when it builds itself correctly, it generally means it builds other polkadot-js repos correctly as well

Overall it is not meant as a scaffold for anything external to polkadot-js, it purely is driven by the need for internal, [very opinionated & very rigdit](https://github.com/polkadot-js/dev/blob/08dffcc3808232fa8b508e49482d41f58fc3f9bd/packages/dev/config/eslint.cjs#L70-L155), tooling for the polkadot-js repos itself. It was never meant as a cli-like tool ala react-create-scripts or something else.